# How do I get the full version of the Roboto font?

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

The [Google Web Fonts version of Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) is missing glyphs like `PALM BRANCH U+2E19` (⸙). How do I get the full version?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Fonts only includes a very trimmed-down version of Roboto. I don't think there's any way to get the full version from Google Fonts as of writing. But you can download the full version of Roboto here:

https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/tree/main/src/hinted

Also, I believe that [this glyph list](https://github.com/googlefonts/roboto/blob/main/res/glyphlist.txt) is out of date - the list doesn't include `PALM BRANCH U+2E19`, and yet Roboto does actually include a glyph for that character. So if you're missing glyphs that you expect Roboto to have, don't rely on that list as a way to check if Roboto actually has it. Instead you should actually download the full font linked above and test it.